# Strange behavior of addEventListener - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a tree structure in React, when I click the right button on any item list context menu appears and there I have various options to choose from. When I click on any of the options appears modal.

And it works. However, the situation changes when instead of specifying a tree structure made rigidly, I enter the tree downloaded from the server(passed by redux). Then suddenly after clicking on options from the context menu modal does not appear.

Before:

```
    componentDidMount(){
      //this.props.getTree()
      document.addEventListener('click', this.hideContextMenu.bind(this))

    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
      document.removeEventListener('click',this.hideContextMenu.bind(this))
    }
```

```
<Container>
                {this.renderSubNodes(treeFromConst)}
```

After the change to pass the tree from server:

```
    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getTree()
      document.addEventListener('click', this.hideContextMenu.bind(this))

    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
      document.removeEventListener('click',this.hideContextMenu.bind(this))
    }
```

```
<Container>
                {treeFromServer && this.renderSubNodes(treeFromServer)}
```

Here is the link to CodeSandbox. I pass tree from const - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/krystianwolanski/ReactAndAspCoreTreeStructure/tree/master/ClientApp?file=/src/TreePage/TreePage.js

What is wrong? I've been tired of it for several days

Answer (score 0):

I changed to window.addEventListener and it's working. Why? I don't know.